# How to remove a query from an HTML table and database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a database with 2 tables:
1st table "data" with columns(name , phone , personid)
2nd table "links" with columns (linkid , link , personid)
Personid is the foreign key that connects the two tables with a "one to many" relationship and it's "CASCADE" when DELETE or UPDATE ,
So one person could have more than 1 link.

The HTMl table looks like that:

```
name    phone    links
jim     432443   link1
                 link2
                 link3
                 .....
_______________________
john    54545    link1
_______________________
...     .....    .....
```

The  code that show database contains on an html table:

```
$state = $connect->prepare("SELECT data.personid, name, phone, link FROM data JOIN links ON data.personid = links.personid");
$state->execute();
$results = $state->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = [];

foreach($results as $result) {

        $data[$result['personid']] = [
            'name' => $result['name'],
            'phone' => $result['phone'],
            'links' => [],
        ];


    $data[$result['personid']]['links'][] = $result['link'];
}

<table>

     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Links</th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>    
        <?php
          foreach ($data as $row) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>".$row['name']."</th>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".implode('<br/>', $row['links'])."</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
             }
         ?>
</table>
```

I want to add a delete functionality to delete some of these data , Like a checkBox next to each query and a button called "Delete Selected" for example, I know how to add the checkBox and the button but I don't know the code to achieve this funcunality .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it works for add please check the code shown here.

On html include this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
<button type="submit">delete</button>
<table>

 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="check_select" readonly="readonly" onclick="toggleselect(this,'delete_data');"></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Links</th>
        </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<?php
      foreach ($data as $row) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" name="checkbox_delete_data[]" value="'.$row['primary_id_of_your_table'].'">';
                    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".implode('<br/>', $row['links'])."</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
         }
     ?>

</table>
</form>
```

In Javascript:

```
function toggleselect(source,chkbox_name) 
{
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox_'+chkbox_name+'[]');

      for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
      }
}
```

Now you can access the selected check box in your action.php file and use it to delete with query.

For example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $selected_check_boxes = implode(',', $_POST["checkbox_delete_data"]);
    $query= $connect->prepare("Delete from table where table.primary id IN ($selected_check_boxes)");
    $query->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , but it's only working with individual deleting , when I choose multiply check boxes SQL Error occuers

Comment: The IDs of the two persons are 2,3 , The error near '2,3' , I think because $selected_check_boxes is inserted to the database as a string

Comment: i have edited my answer please add brackets around the parameter after IN

Comment: why you're using prepare here?

Comment: @AbdalAsif thanks it's working now , What if I want to know the number of deleted queries how could I do that ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense i normally use $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) but in this i went on the same pattern just to clear

Comment: @Sam u can use mysqli_affected_rows() for that. glad it helped. please mark the answer as useful if ur problem is solved

Comment: thanks , I will , I have to refresh the page each time I delete a query to see that it's removed how can the changes done without refreshing the page ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank u for the link i see what u were trying to explain. Is it to prevent sql injection?

Comment: @Sam u can do that with ajax

Comment: @AbdalAsif I don't know ajax , Can you tell me what should I search for to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomnend to make whole table in < form > and add some "data-" attribute with personId to each checkbox. Then handle (when form submitted) these attributes with javascript and merge the SQL query like

```
delete from data where personid (1,2,3, ...)
```

If you need more help i can write some code, but develop it by own is always better :)

Cheers